# Easy-to-use Java JSON library with high read-only performance

Tags: java, json

I'm working on abstracting a way to handle JSON however I've noticed a large number of libraries to read JSON.

I've done some prior research and found that some libraries are great with small files, some are better with large files but suffer with smaller files.

Ultimately, I would like one which is kind of a median of these since I don't know how large the files are when reading; they could be a few KB, couple of MB or even a GB (which is unlikely as I intend to use this for reading JSON from files on the disk)

To add, it doesn't *have* to have nice writing abilities because, as said above, I intend to use it purely for reading files rather than writing to them.

Simply put, I would like a library that is nothing fancy; no serializing to objects or vice versa, no converting to JSON at compile time — it simply has to convert a JSON string into a respective object and array classes to make it possible to search through the hierarchy.

So, which is the most suitable? I've had experience with all of these but I'm not sure which is the most suitable (or fastest, however I don't think it would be noticeable) for my needs. If I had to choose between ease-of-use or reading speed I would prefer ease-of-use due to the fact that reading speed couldn't differ too much from library to library (can it?)

Comment: The way the question is written at the moment does IMHO not fit this site. The title suggests that we may only recommend one of the existing three, which is not the idea of this site. Maybe you're missing a fourth great JSON library. Next, your requirements are vague. It should handle small files, but how small? It should handle large files, but what is large for you? 10 MB, 1 GB, 6TB? And it should be fast, but how fast with which data on which machine?

Comment: I've edited it to try and make it less vague and edit requirements slightly

Comment: Read-only? Write too? What kind of operations Do you need compile-time or real-time object marshalling class generation?

Comment: Tried, again, to make it less vague

Comment: If you had to choose between reading speed and ease-of-use, which one would you choose?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul ease-of-use would be my preference